# Facebook like button, default image is too late?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I have wordpress site, i added like button for share post.
But, i don't knew than i came loaded default image ...

Some post are shared with captcha's image... not good !

I have added :

but it's always captcha's image on like button :/

One idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an image for the Facebook scraper to use when posting/sharing to Facebook using the [og:image](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/) Open Graph meta tag:

```
<head>
   <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/share_image.jpg" />
</head>
```

Once you have specified a new Open Graph image, you can ask Facebook to scrape the page again to get the new image using the Open Graph Debugger:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

The Debugger (formerly the "Linter") will also let you preview what Facebook will post for any of your pages, it's a handy tool.

I'm sure there are [plenty of WordPress plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=facebook%20open%20graph) which you can use to automatically set up Open Graph tags on your website. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have added line : `<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/share_image.jpg" />` 
On facebook's debug i have somes warnings but it find my default picture... ! I don't want used any plugins !